# Compass/Grunt Translate Mixin Error

Tags: gruntjs, compass-sass

Using Compass 1.0.0, when I try and use the `translate` mixin within a separate scss file, I keep getting the below error when using Grunt Compass.

error library/sass/main.scss (Line 391 of /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.0.rc.1/stylesheets/compass/css3/_transform.scss: Mixin transform takes 1 argument but 2 were passed.)

I have my files split up like this:

```
|_ all.scss
    |_ partials/
          _footer.scss
```

In all.scss

```
@import "compass";
@import "partials/footer";
```

In partials/footer.scss:

```
div {
  @include translate( -50%, -50% );
}
```

For some reason, I can't use the `translate` mixin. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with sass or compass version. I've tried it in sassmeister and it works.

Answer (score 1):

there seem to be some issues with grunt using compass. using the translate mixin without comma separation should probably work:

```
div {
  @include translate(-50% -50%);
}
```